# Integrating with respect to varying measures

Tags: integration, measure-theory, reference-request, terminology

I have stumbled upon an unusual integration, and I don't know if this has a name or even if this is valid. MWE:

Let $\mu (\cdot | y)$ be a finite measure, supported over some $\mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}$, for all $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ where $\mathcal{Y}$ is a closed interval. Let $A(t) \subset \mathcal{X}$ so that for all $x \in A(t)$ we have $t - x \in \mathcal{Y}$. The integration I want to define roughly looks like:
$$ \int_{x \in A(t)} \mathrm{d} \mu(x | t-x ).$$

The problem here is that the integration is over $x$, however, depending on $x$ the measure is also changing. Is there a condition on the measure or $A(t)$ so that this integral is defined?

Comment: How are the $\mu$'s related? Are they, for example, all absolutely continuous with respect to some fixed measure?

Comment: @Ian I have 0 assumptions and I am trying to figure out the minimum amount of assumptions needed where this integration is well-defined.

Comment: If they're all absolutely continuous with respect to some fixed $\nu$ then you can write it as $\int_{A(t)} \frac{d\mu(x;t-x)}{d\nu} d\nu$ using Radon-Nikodym, then write that as $\int_{\mathcal{X}} \frac{d\mu(x;t-x)}{d\nu} 1_{A(t)}(x) d\nu(x)$. This RN derivative is just a function of $t$ and $x$ so this is well defined. I'm not 100% sure it means what you want it to mean, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful comment! For example, if all $\mu(\cdot | y)$ are a.c. wrt Lebesgue measure, does that mean writing $ \int_{x \in A(t)} \mathrm{d} \mu(x | t-x )$ is well-defined? You showed that in this condition the integration is well-defined, but I am now wondering, is the way I represent it 'odd', or is this fine?

Comment: In effect what I did is saying "compute the RN derivative $\frac{d\mu_p}{d\nu}$ for each fixed $p$, then set $p=t-x$ and integrate". In this regard really the $x$ in the integration variable and the $x$ in the parameter are not actually the same variable conceptually, and they just get related through the substitution at the end. Does that make any sense?

Comment: In particular, what you're writing is not literally well-defined, but if what I described matches the concept you were trying to define, then now you have a reasonable way to define it.

Comment: @Ian Thank you very much. I understand that we are using the RN derivative to change the integration with respect to a single measure, with varying functions. I can also see that this holds if all $\mu(\cdot | y)$ are a.c. w.r.t. a single finite measure, which helps us here. 

If this is indeed correct, then we are only using the identity
$$\underbrace{\dfrac{\mathrm{d} \mu( \cdot | t - x)}{\mathrm{d}{\nu}}}_{\text{RN derivative}}(x) \cdot \mathrm d \nu (x) =   \mathrm{d} \mu (x | t-x) $$
So wouldn't it then immediately imply 
$$ \int_{A(t)} \mathrm{d} \mu)(x | t-x) $$
is just fine?

Comment: Not really, because of the distinction I made: the RN derivative involves changing the integration variable, and what I described does that without *also* changing the parameter. Then I went back and plugged in $p=t-x$ at the end, after $\frac{d\mu_p}{d\nu}$ (a function of $x$ and $p$ on the same footing) was determined.

Comment: You might be interested in transition kernels: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel These are be used to define joint probability distributions $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ by specifying the conditional marginal distributions $X_j \mid X_1, \dots, X_{j - 1}$.